# Unable to List All SharePoint Online Lists Using SharePoint SPFX Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepointframework

I'm new to SharePoint SPFX development. As I am new to SharePoint SPFx, I was trying the below Microsoft Official Tutorial Connect your client-side web part to SharePoint (Hello World part 2) .

I successfully completed Part 01 of the tutorial series, Build your first SharePoint client-side web part (Hello World part 1)

When I'm following Part 02 I got stuck at the below 2 methods

01

```
 private _renderListAsync(): void {
    this._getListData()
      .then((response) => {
        this._renderList(response.value);
      })
      .catch(() => {});
  }
```

The error is in line 4 (response.value), which is 'Argument of type 'ISPLists[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISPList[]'.
Type 'ISPLists' is missing the following properties from type 'ISPList': Title, Idts(2345)'

Also in the same method line 6 (.catch(() => {});), which is 'Unexpected empty arrow function.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function'

02

```
private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists?$filter=Hidden eq false`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch(() => {}); 
  }
```

The error is in line 6 (.catch(() => {});), whcich is Unexpected empty arrow function.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function

I tried many threads but didn't get an answer.

I'm using SharePoint Online, NodeJs 16.20.0, NPM 8.19.4 without using any front-end framework like React or Angular.

Please refer to the below link for the source code for the solution.
[Souce code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RccnNmjIDdqeOvUxg-cnG-byxVwuhNe8?usp=share_link)
Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Best regards,
ChiranthakaJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the questions.

1. For the issue in '`.catch(() => {});`' use '`.catch((err) => { console.log(err); });`'
2. For the issue 'ISPList[]'. Type 'ISPLists' is missing the following properties from type 'ISPList': Title, Idts(2345)' complete the source code by following the instructions till the end of the tutorial page 2 and the issue will automatically will disappear.